# Finding streamlines for a particular combination of $u$ & $v$ components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow

[image]

I am  trying to solve the first part of this fluids problem from the Munson text but I am not getting the right answer. The way I solved this was by doing $$\overrightarrow V \times d\vec s = 0; d\vec s = \hat idx + \hat jdy $$
Then from this cross-product I set each of the components to zero - so in this case we only have the component for $\hat k$. Then I took the integral which is $$\int[c(x^2 - y^2)]dy + \int[2cxy]dx = 0$$
Doing this integration I get $$2x^2y - \frac {y^3}{3} = C$$ What am I not understanding here? $x$ & $y$ are coordinates independent of each other correct?

PS: Not a homework problem. Just a professional revising fluid mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\vec V \times d\vec s = \vec 0$ gives the following equation for the $\hat k$-th component:
$$c(x^2 - y^2)dy + 2cxydx = 0,$$
which is a differential equation that you have to solve in order to obtain the sought relation between $x$ and $y$. Assuming $x$ and $y$ are independent variables is definitely wrong (we are looking for a relation between the two after all).

Some hints for solving the equation:

rewrite the equation in the form
$$2xy\frac{dx}{dy} + x^2 = y^2,$$
and notice that
$$2x\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dx^2}{dy}$$
and
$$ x^2 = x^2\frac{dy}{dy}.$$
You take it from here.

Comment: Ah! I just noticed I made a mistake in the question: Yes, the second integral is w.r.t to $x$. Using your hints I eventually reached what looked like an expansion of the product rule. Thank you for your help. Can you tell me why performing the integral on that first equation w.r.t. $x$ & $y$ isn't correct?

Comment: You can't evaluate the integrals unless you know the relation between $x$ and $y$, which is the thing we're looking after and which gives us the equation of the streamline. (As I said above, it is wrong to evaluate the integrals assuming that $x$ and $y$ are independent, because they aren't).

Comment: But in a stream function/equation of streamline, $\psi(x,y)$, the $x$ & $y$ are independent variables. If I were integrating $\psi$ w.r.t. $x$ or $y$ then I would be integrating partially. Is it possible that the method you suggest works because after manipulation the differential equation becomes separable in $y$ and $x^2y$?